# Django url templatetag (but not reverse() ) error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to use the url template tag as such:

```
{% url all-labs-map %}
```

but when i view the page, i get this error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'all-labs-map' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

When I use the template tag like this:

```
{% url gmaps.views.all_labs %}
```

It works just fine.

Here's the URL conf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('gmaps.views',
    url(r'^lab_list/$', 'all_labs', name="all-labs-map" ),
)
```

I tried using the django shell to see if there was a problem with the named URL, but using

```
reverse('all-labs-map')
```

returns the correct URL.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Thanks!

Majd

EDIT:

I am using django 1.2 on ubuntu with nginx server and gunicorn and virtualenv. I'm having another trouble with a custom tag where the library loads, but the tag itself is not recognized even though i'm using the correct tag registration syntax. Any ideas would be very greatly appreciated!

Comment: looks like you are doing everything right and have a mystery.  Please update when you figure it out.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is, did you restart the nginx service after making the changes to your urls.py etc? As a rule of thumb, you should restart the service after changing any .py files - not doing so will cause reverse() and {% url %} to intermittently work and not work

Comment: @skyl is right, the `URLNode` would eventually call `reverse('all-labs-map', (), {}, contex.current_app)`, which works for you, so it's definitely something else.

Comment: Just to make sure, i did restart nginx, and the problem is still there.

Comment: ever find out what was going on here?

Comment: not really... I moved the exact same code to a new virtualenv, and that solved the problem. It also added to my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is still high in Google results, but no one has answered it correctly yet.  The key is this:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

Prior to Django 1.3, this was the syntax for the `url` templatetag:

```
{% url view_name arg1 %}
```

In Django 1.5, this will be the syntax:

```
{% url "view_name" arg1 %}
```

[Starting in Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url), the old version works but gives you a deprecation warning, telling you to `{% load url from future %}` and switch to the new version of that templatetag, in preparation for Django 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enclosing the name of the url in quotes like so:

```
{% url "all-labs-map" %}
```

or

```
{% url 'all-labs-map' %}
```

I've had some problems with URLs once and this seemed to help. 
Also regarding @user608133 comment - you need to restart gunicorn rather than nginx, as nginx is just a proxy...

Comment: I had the opposite - would not work in singles but then with no quotes it worked.  The docs have it in quotes as well..

Comment: As for me, I got this very kind of error (named urls, working in views and shell, but raising template error). Your post pays my attention to quotes and viola! - It started working when I removed them. It's kind of strange behavior, but it's a fact...

Comment: I'm glad it helped you guys. I've too experienced a bit unpredictable behaviour over time... maybe it's just different versions of Django...

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur if you have another url with the same name overriding this one that requires multiple parameters. Is there any duplicates found when you do a search in your entire project for 'all-labs-map'?

Comment: The only named URL with the name all-labs-map is the one i mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm... this another elementary idea... but any chance that the main urls file is not pointing to gmaps.urls?

Comment: well, reverse('all-labs-map') would not work if it wasn't pointed, since     url(r'^lab_list/$', 'all_labs', name="all-labs-map" ),
 is in my gmaps.urls. Thanks for trying anyway ;) Let me know if you have any more ideas.