# {% url %} gives me NoReverseMatch error while reverse() returns the url just fine. Why?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-registration, django-1.4

I don't know if this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157976/django-url-templatetag-but-not-reverse-error-caught-noreversematch-while-r) is of the same problem that I am about to describe, but it does share the same symptoms. Unfortunately, it still remains unresolved as I am writing.

So here is my problem. I am trying to add James Bennett's [django-registration app](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) to my django project. I have pretty much finished configuring it to my needs - custom templates and urls. Just when I thought everything was good to go. I got `NoReverseMatch` error from using `{% url 'testing' item_id=123 %}` (I also tried using the view name, `myapp.views.test`, instead but no luck) in one of the custom templates required by django-registration. Interestingly, I tried `reverse('testing', kwargs={'item_id':123})` in the shell and the url was returned just fine. I thought `{% url %}` uses `reverse()` in the back-end but why did I get different outcomes?

**urls.py:** (the URLconf of my site)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^test/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'test', name='testing'),
)
```

**activation_email.txt:** (the said template. Note it's intentionally in *.txt* extension as required by django-registration and that shouldn't be the cause of the problem.)

```
{% comment %}Used to generate the body of the activation email.{% endcomment %}
Welcome to {{ site }}! Please activate your account by clicking on the following link:

{% url 'testing' item_id=123 %}

Note the activation link/code will be expired in {{ expiration_days }} days.
```

I don't know if it matters but just thought I should mention **activation_email.txt** is stored in the *templates* directory of `myapp` though it is used by `django-registration`.

Also, I am using django 1.4

I have a feeling that the problem has something to do with the url namespaces, a topic that I have never understood, but it's just a naive guess. (IMO, the django documentation is great in explaining everything about django, except when it comes to url namespaces)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm no expert here, but in a Django project I'm working on at the moment I use the name of the url without quotes.  I just added quotes around a similar line in one of my templates and it produced the same error as your error.

Try:

```
{% url testing item_id=123 %}
```

Comment: Interesting~ that works!! Thanks a lot. But what's the rationale behind this? I mean all of the examples of `{% url %}` in the django docs use quotes.

Comment: Check the named urls section of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns   As far as I can tell, if you are using url tags with an actual path to the view then you need the quotes.  If using a name, you don't.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In the template tags document, there is an example `{% url 'myapp:view-name' %}`, so I thought qoutes were needed for using view name. I guess that applies only when I use view name together with namespace, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ahmoo, they are getting rid of the unquoted url tag in 1.5, you can `{% load url from future %}` to use the new tag behavior which always uses quotes, unless of course you are passing in a variable which resolves to a string.

Comment: After a little experimentation, what I said earlier about needing quotes if you use the path.to.the.view is not true.  I added quotes to other url tags and got the same error. Seems that no quotes at all is the way to go.  I'm using 1.4.  Interesting bit of info from @YujiTomita regarding 1.5

Comment: @John - Here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) to the info mentioned by YujiTomita. It should have been also put into the relevant sections of the official docs.